# Why is the variance of the estimator in Buffon's Needle Problem when the length of the needle is optimal larger than other cases?

Tags: probability, statistics

It has been shown that the optimal length of a needle in Buffon's original Needle problem to compute $\pi$ in the least number of throws is:

Let $l $ be the length of the needle and $w$ be the width of the parallel grid

$l=  w$

Hence, the probability of a needle intersecting a line is given by $ \frac{2}{\pi}$.

The variance of the estimator (q) for this case for M throws is:

($X_m$ is the Bernoulli outcome of whether or not the needle intersects a line)

$\hat{q}= \frac{1}{M}\sum\limits_{i=1}^Mx_m$

Hence, $Var(\hat{q}) = \frac{1}{M}\frac{2}{\pi}(1 - \frac{2}{\pi})$

But, this is worse than th case where $l = \frac{w}{2}$ where the variance of the estimator $\hat{q}$ is given by $\frac{1}{M}\frac{1}{\pi}(1 - \frac{1}{\pi})$ which is smaller for any given $M$.

Why is this the case?